# How to wait for a certain value coming from a react-native hook before proceeding?

Tags: react-native

I have a custom react-native hook that return either true or false, depending on the useState defind within it.  In another component, I use the result returned by the hook to load certain data depending on it.

here is the hook that I have created, that returns subscribed:

```
export const useHasSubscription = () => { 
  const [appState, setAppState] = useState(AppState.currentState);
  const [subscribed, setSubscribed] = useState(null)
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true)

  const {
    connected,
    subscriptions,
    getSubscriptions,
  } = useIAP();

  useEffect(() => {
    
    console.log("Connected? ", connected, "App State: ", appState)
    if (!connected) {
      console.log('not connected')
      return;
    }
    if (appState === "active") {
      console.log('app is active, checking status')
      getSubscriptions({ skus: ["sku"] }).then(()=>{
        return IapIosSk2.subscriptionStatus("sku")
      }).then((res) => {
          console.log("subscription Status: ", res);
          const temp = res.some(({state})=> (
            state === 'subscribed' || state === 'inGracePeriod'
           ));
          setSubscribed(temp);
        })
        .catch((err) => { //test here with error/no internet 
          console.log("failed to get status: ", err);
        });

    }
    setLoading(false)
  }, [
    connected,
    appState,
    getSubscriptions,
    subscribed,
    isLoading]);

    return subscribed
};
```

Here, when the app loads, it calls this hook and sets isSubscribed to either true or false

```
const AppLoaded = () => {

  const isSubscribed = useHasSubscription(); // wait for it to either be false or true, not null

  console.log("is Subbed? " + isSubscribed);

  return (
    <PaperProvider theme={theme}>
      <SafeAreaProvider>
        {isSubscribed ? (
          <NavigationRoot />
        ) : (
          <SubscriptionScreen />
        )}
      </SafeAreaProvider>
    </PaperProvider>
  );
};
```

However, this component begins with null, so it defaults to the

```
          <SubscriptionScreen />
```

component, then finally the isSubscribed finished and updates to either false or true, which messes with the flow of the app.  How can I wait for useHasSubscription() to not return null/wait for it to finish all the way? Because currently it is not going through the entire useEffect within the hook and is just returning null instantly, before finishing useHasSubscription()

I have tried making the hook async but it throws many errors when I try to call it in the appLoaded component.

Answer (score 1):

you can try something like this

```
const AppLoaded = () => {

 const isSubscribed = useHasSubscription(); // wait for it to either be false or true, not null

 console.log("is Subbed? " + isSubscribed);
 
 // since you specifically asked for `null`
 // this will not work for "", undefined, false, 0, or NaN
 if(isSubscribed === null) return <Loading /> // or whatever you want

 return (
  <PaperProvider theme={theme}>
    <SafeAreaProvider>
      {isSubscribed ? (
        <NavigationRoot />
      ) : (
        <SubscriptionScreen />
      )}
    </SafeAreaProvider>
  </PaperProvider>
 );
};
```